# About the general method to compute the number of zeros of complex polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, contour-integration

I read the following questions accidentally:

For any fixed real number t, what is the number of zeros of polynomial $p(z) = z^5+2z^3+z^2+z-t$. (in this case, let's say exclude those duplicated roots, which will make this question trivial.)

Then another question is, to the above polynomial, how to calculate its root numbers in a specific area, for example, the left side of the complex plane (Real z < 0?)

Are there any suitable tools in, for example, contour analysis, to solve this general question?

Comment: What do you mean by read the question accidentally?  You tried not to look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the amount of roots without counting the multiplicity, we just need to filter out the duplicate roots.

Suppose the $\alpha$ is a root with multiplicity $m$, then $(x-\alpha)^m\mid f(x)$. Writing $f(x)=(x-\alpha)^mP(x)$ with $x-\alpha\not \mid P(x)$. Then by calculus, we know:
$$(x-\alpha)^{m-1}\mid f'(x)=(x-\alpha)^{m-1}((x-\alpha)P'(x)+mP(x))$$
Since $(x-\alpha)\not\mid P(x)$, then $(x-\alpha)^{m}\not\mid f'(x)$. This shows that for each root $\alpha$, $f'(x)$ has exactly one less the multiplicity, then $\frac {f(x)}{\gcd(f(x),f'(x))}$ contains exactly the roots with multiplicity $1$. So the amount of unique roots is $\deg(f)-\deg(\gcd (f,f'))$

Comment: Thanks, by the way, how to judge the roots' distribution situation, for example, how many unique roots, or currently, simply roots, are on the left of the plane. (Real <=0)?

Comment: @qwerty I don't think there's a easy method to do it by hand except to "plot" it out. And by "plotting", I mean to plug in some values of $x$ for $f$ and $f'$, and determine can it have anymore root. For each specific polynomial, there will be different tricks to use along the way. If you really want a answer, you could maybe open another question.

Answer (score 0):

The number of zeros (or number of roots) of a polynomial, including multiplicities is the degree of the polynomial.  Here the degree is five (the term with the highest power of $z$ is $z^5$).

So $p(z)$ has five zeros in the complex plane.

Comment: Yes, but what if I also ask for the number of the unique roots (exclude those duplicated roots), how to judge this, then?

Comment: You are right, the original question was trivial and I see that you edited it.  Great!